# Ruby - unexpected return (LocalJumpError)

Tags: ruby

Ruby 2.0

Why would the code below give unexpected return (LocalJumpError) ?

```
# some code here
puts "Scanning for xml files .."
zip_files = Dir.entries(directory).select { |f| File.extname(f) == '.zip' }
if(zip_files.count == 0)
    puts "No files found, exiting..."
    return
end
# more code here ( if files found)
```

`Error: unexpected return (LocalJumpError)`

```
No files found, exiting...
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: just remove `return`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not in a method. You cannot [`return`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) from there. If you want to exit early, use [`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit).

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, you could rescue the `LocalJumpError`

```
puts "Scanning for xml files .."
zip_files = Dir.entries(directory).select { |f| File.extname(f) == '.zip' }

begin
  return unless zip_files.count > 0

  # more code here ( if files found)
rescue LocalJumpError
  puts "No files found, exiting..."
end
```

Comment: That is a complete misuse of exceptions as a flow-control mechanism.